# Generate similarity score in percentage from SIFT using opencv

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, sift

I have been trying to find a way to generate similarity score ( in %) after comparing two images using SIFT in python (2.7.x) opencv (2.4.9). I was only able to find examples that draw lines between matches. How do I proceed with this.

Comment: to be exact i'm looking for python implementation of  VL_UBCMATCH function

Comment: Did you find it ?

Comment: No I couldn't find it. An example code would be really helpful

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/51728654/1021819 help?

Answer (score 6):

There is an opencv equivalent of vl_ubcmatch function in Matlab.

Here is the excerpt from [opencv documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html).

```
# create BFMatcher object
bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)

# Match descriptors.
matches = bf.match(des1,des2)
```

`matches = bf. match (des1, des2)` matches the two sets of descriptors and returns a list of DMatch objects. This DMatch object has four attributes: distance, trainIdx, queryIdx, imgIdx. These return values are equivalent of vl_ubcmatch function.

I hope you will find it helpful.

Comment: What I need is score. VL_UBCMATCH in addition to matches returns score

Comment: According to [VLFEAT documentation](http://www.vlfeat.org/matlab/vl_ubcmatch.html), VL_UBCMATCH returns the squared Euclidean distance to the score variable. In fact, when I try [SIFT Tutorial](http://www.vlfeat.org/overview/sift.html), the score variable has distance values between the two SIFT descriptors. scores(:, 1)  is 21647, and `sum((int64(da(:, 9)) - int64(db(:, 618))) .^2)` is same value , where da(:, 9) is 9th SIFT descriptor in ImageA, db(:, 618) is 618th SIFT descriptor in ImageB. Isn't this your desired output?